# How to get the href value (which changes based on session) from the "Inspect Element"

Tags: html, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

Requirement:
To get the data from a URL into S3 and build a data pipeline. I am trying to get the dataset using python requests.get().

However, the URL changes every few minutes, and it becomes difficult to fetch the data using requests.get() without manual changes to the python script.

My Approach:
I am able to get the data to S3 and build the data pipeline. However, the URL is dynamic I am kinda stuck there.

Code:

```
import json
import requests
import boto3
import csv
import re


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response= requests.get("https://calcat.covid19.ca.gov/cacovidmodels/_w_d58f724d/session/d37479fcceb6b02080b6b7c23dd05046/download/dl.custom?w=d58f724d",verify=False)
    #print(response.content)
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',region_name='us-west-2')
    with open('/tmp/data.csv', 'w') as datacsvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(datacsvfile, delimiter=",")
        for line in response.iter_lines():
                writer.writerows([line.strip().split(',')])
```

Query:
How can I get the href from the "Inspect element" section , store it in a variable and create a dynamic URL to make a REST call to. Below is the "Inspect element" code I am referring to :

[image]

This href only appears in the "inspect element" and not in the "View Source Code".

Comment: Why is this tagged selenium? Your code indicates no usage of selenium.

Comment: Is there a parent page (that contains the dynamic url you want to fetch) that you can use to FIND the url that is dynamic?

Comment: Hi @DMart, I was trying to achieve this using python. However, I checked for few solutions and found out that selenium would be the way, hence tagged as selenium. All we need is to hit the URL : https://calcat.covid19.ca.gov/cacovidmodels, click on "Downloads" on top , then under the section "Custom Datasets" once we have the dropdown populated, right click on "Download custom Dataset" , and grab the href value ; which would be something like the one in screenshot above, and store it in a variable. We can then create a URL similar to the one in my code, and use python requests to get the value

Comment: You may be able to do this all with python requests and bypass the browser. I think you just need to learn how to do a form submission (POST request) via python.

Comment: @DMart I tried using python requests: [code] import requests

url = "https://calcat.covid19.ca.gov/cacovidmodels/"
payload = {'cust_dl_type':'Current'}
r = requests.post(url, payload)
print(r.content); but I keep getting 400 error

Comment: That feels like another question :)

Comment: @DMart do you have any sample code snippet, that I can have a look at.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223759/discussion-between-jeet-and-dmart).